# Google Maps with Custom Background Image

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm hoping to find a way to create a google maps instance with a custom background image. I've seen a few examples (linked below) but haven't found any documentation on how to do this. I'm hoping someone could PLEASE help me with this.

Thanks!

[Simple Example](http://www.obsidianportal.com/campaigns/60326/maps/35830)
[Advanced Example](http://brickellhouse.com/location.php)

Comment: You are looking for custom map type in google maps api. Here is the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes?hl=pl#ImageMapTypes.

Comment: The second link needs to be either update or removed, Looks like it's changed, now It contains ads and potentially offensive material.

Answer (score -2):

> Your first example is only an map image not Google maps,

[image]

For customizing the **Google maps** you can check the [Styling the Base Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/customizing/styling-the-base-map) and [style maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling).